# I don't understand how my compiler got this output in C++

Tags: c++

My C++ program is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int a;
struct CARE{
    long L1;
    void init()
    {
        L1=100;
    }
    void intake()
    {
        a++;
        L1+=++a;
    }
    void takeout()
    {
        int k=5;
        cout<<a*k<<'#'<<L1-a;
    }
};
int main()
{
    CARE c[3];
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
       c[i].init();
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
       c[j].intake();
    for(int m=0;m<3;m++)
       c[m].takeout();
    return 0;
    getch();
}
```

And the output comes out to be:

> 30#9630#9830#100

According to me 'a' would be a junk variable and every output would be different from the other but that is not the case here. Can someone explain why?

Comment: OT: your should indent the code in `main` properly

Comment: @Jabberwocky Sorry about that... just edited it

Comment: Indenting correctly is essentially good for _you_.

Comment: There is no guarantee that uninitialized local scope variables will contain junk. There is no guarantee that they won't, either. Newer compilers are erring towards automatically initialising all variables to zero for security.

Comment: @Ben _Newer compilers are erring towards automatically initialising all variables to zero for security_. Do you have any reference for this?

Comment: @Ben I very much hope not. That could create all sort of bugs when porting to a different compiler.

Comment: @Ben - that's simply not true.   Yours is a false claim that has been circulating for years, and rebutted by some quite notable experts.  With too many compilers, zero-initialising variables of automatic storage duration is simply too expensive, particularly in cases where the next operation performed on that variable is to assign it another value.

Comment: For security reasons your OS may initialize memory it gives to your process to 0. This is probably the effect you see when you think the compiler is initializing local variables to 0.

Comment: @Jabberwocky For msvc I believe the flag `/d1initall` does this. This flag is applied automatically if you specify `/kernel`. https://twitter.com/JosephBialek/status/1062774315098112001

Comment: @Peter "To date, we are seeing noise level performance regressions caused by this change. We accomplished this by improving the compilers ability to kill redundant stores. While everything is initialized at declaration, most of these initializations can be proven redundant and eliminated" 
https://twitter.com/JosephBialek/status/1062777272715726849

Comment: @Bathsheba Of course I mean "all otherwise uninitialized variables", if that's what you are getting at..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a` is at global scope, so it's initialised to `0`.

(Indeed if it was declared in a function then it would not be initialised and your program behaviour would be undefined.)

Comment: Every global variable is initialised as 0 by default?

Comment: @Sujit yes, they are

Comment: @Jabberwocky Oh.. I didn't know.. I tried googling around but didn't find anything.. Thanks!

Comment: @Sujit Read static intialization part of this [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization)